# DropDownListFor Helper Makes Wrong Selection When Pre-Populating Null Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm using MVC3 to populate an HTML form from a database. A number of the form elements are drop-down lists (selects). I'm using the "DropDownListFor" helper to pre-populate the lists and to perform data binding on POSTing of edited data (which works just fine).

I have a few nullable fields in the database where "NULL/Empty String" is a legitimate default value. So instead of "high", "medium" and "low" as 3 possible options, it uses "high", "medium" and "", where the empty string or null value is equivalent to "low". I've mirrored this behavior in the drop-down lists so that they provide corresponding text/value pairs.

The problem is with the model binding when it pre-populates the drop-down list and selects a default value to display in the DDL based on the value in the database. If the incoming database value is "high", it properly selects the "high" option. If the database value is "medium", it properly selects the "medium" option. BUT - if the database value is NULL/empty string, it selects the "medium" option and not the "low" option (or no "selected" at all, which is what I would have expected)! It's properly inserting the default optionLabel at the top of the list as per the DropDownListFor overload I'm using, but then it's promptly overwriting it by tagging 'selected="selected"' onto the "medium" option - where is that coming from?

Here is the code in the controller;

```
IcxPdcEditViewModel editViewModel = new IcxPdcEditViewModel()
{
    TwoPlusEmptyDDL = twoPlusEmptyList.TwoPlusEmptyList
};
return View(editViewModel);
```

where a helper sets up the DDL as follows;

```
public class PDCTwoPlusEmptyList
{
    public List<SelectListItem> TwoPlusEmptyList { get; set; }
    public PDCTwoPlusEmptyList()
    {
        this.TwoPlusEmptyList = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "medium", Value = "medium" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "high", Value = "high" }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding code in the View;

```
<td>Maintenance:</td>
<td><%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Plant.Maintenance, Model.TwoPlusEmptyDDL, "low") %></td>
```

Here is the resulting HTML source code when the database value is NULL/empty string (confirmed);

```
<td><b>Maintenance</b>*:</td>
<td><select id="Plant_Maintenance" name="Plant.Maintenance">
  <option value="">low</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="medium">medium</option>
  <option value="high">high</option>
</select></td>
```

One last thought, I am not using a ViewBag at all, and there are no conflicting names in my ViewData.

Any thoughts on what is causing this behavior?

Comment: The only way that `"medium"` can be selected is if the value of `Maintenance` is `"medium"`. But something does not look right with your html - its generating `id="_Maintenance"` (there should not be an underscore character) so something else is going on.

Comment: I've edited the code to show the full IDs and names - I had removed them for clarity, although I guess that could cause some confusion. And I can assure you from some very active debugging that the database field "Maintenance" is NULL while "medium" is selected. I can't explain it.

Comment: And I can assure that that of the value of `Plant.Maintenance` is `null` then the first ("low") option will be selected (and you can view the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) which shows that internally the helper generates a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` property based on the value of the model). I suggest you include a `<div>@Model.Plant.Maintenance</div>` in you view and check the output

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio and I've inserted breaks in the Controller where I can see the values being sent to the View, along with the values as read from the database. I will do what you've said, though, just in case somehow the data is being corrupted or intercepted on its way to the View. I'll report back.

Comment: I did what you suggested, and it confirms what I am reporting - Model.Plant.Maintenance on the View is "" and yet the "Selected" property is being set on the "medium" option. By the way, I have at least 4 other fields with nullable DDLs on this form, and they all behave this way - they all seem to revert to the top select option when the database presents a NULL value.

Comment: Then there must be something else in your code you have not shown causing the issue (and I'm assuming this is from a GET call and you have not done something like try and change the value in a POST method and returned the view)

Comment: Yes, this is from a GET call.

Comment: All I can suggest is you edit the question to show the full code in the GET method.

Answer (score 0):

I've found and fixed the problem, thanks to a whole lot of debugging! :)

The issue was that I was reusing a single instance of the "PDCTwoPlusEmptyList" for 4 different drop-down lists on a single form (i.e. a single view), as a way to conserve code in the controller. This "reusable" DDL object was able to properly reset the "Selected" flag to match the value incoming from the database EXCEPT when the value was NULL, in which case it "remembered" the value from the previous DDL. The solution was to create a separate instance of the PDCTwoPlusEmptyList for each of the DDLs on the page - everything works properly now. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue - reusing the `List<SelectListItem>`, and finding that the selected value was not being set correctly by `DropDownListFor` when the value was null. Having stepped into the code in `System.Web.Mvc`, I found the reason.

The call stack looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes)
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool allowMultiple, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
```

And the code for SelectInternal looks like this:

```
private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool allowMultiple, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);

    // ...

    bool usedViewData = false;

    // If we got a null selectList, try to use ViewData to get the list of items.
    if (selectList == null)
    {
        selectList = htmlHelper.GetSelectData(name);
        usedViewData = true;
    }

    object defaultValue = (allowMultiple) ? htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string[])) : htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));

    // If we haven't already used ViewData to get the entire list of items then we need to
    // use the ViewData-supplied value before using the parameter-supplied value.
    if (defaultValue == null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        if (!usedViewData)
        {
            defaultValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(name);
        }
        else if (metadata != null)
        {
            defaultValue = metadata.Model;
        }
    }

    if (defaultValue != null)
    {
        selectList = GetSelectListWithDefaultValue(selectList, defaultValue, allowMultiple);
    }

    // ...
}
```

When `SelectInternal` is called, the `defaultValue` variable is used to store the value from the model. This is tested for `null`, and if the value is **not** `null`, then the `selectList` is overwritten with a new list, with the selected attribute set for the list item that matches the `defaultValue`.

If on a subsequent call to `SelectInternal` the defaultValue **is** `null`, then the `selectList` is not updated, so the selected item in the list remains the same as the most recent call that had a non-null value and used the same `selectList`.

Some possible options for dealing with this behaviour:

- Use a separate List for each list (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804743/13153))
- Write a custom HtmlHelper that clears the selected attribute for all list items
- Clone the List before passing it into DropDownListFor, so the original list is never modified